# requireJs - does it really help performance?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, client-side

I am trying to decide whether or not to use [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/) on my projects.

I know on Chrome and Firefox assets download in parallel but are executed in the order they were coded..I think it's about 8 parallel downloads, so each file is cached separately,
so if I change one file, it would be better for the website performance, because the rest were left unchanged and cached. So what is all the fuss and huss about RequireJs?

Comment: Benchmark it and then make your decision.

Comment: but I want to understand, not just look at results with wonder...because I just doesn't make any sense this method would be better than a bunch of minified, gziped JS files

Comment: Maybe it isn't better. Test it and be sure.

Comment: rharper covered this really well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11531091/723007

Comment: thanks, your post link helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the answer is, the way I see it, RequireJs is not about performance, but is rather a tool to load scripts that are associated with DOM modules, completely separating things. Performance is not an issue, and I was asking the wrong question.

Comment: Buy the way, after years of asking this question, I am now using [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org/) with Gulp and Babel so I could use ES6 imports/exports and have everything bundled into one nice file (for performance/caching)